# why am i getting this error in simple angularjs program?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting this error,

`Argument 'ctrl1' is not a function, got undefined`

on running the latest angularjs v1.3.15.
Should my syntax be any different here?

This is the html

```
<body ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">

      {{color}}

      {{root_color}}

  </div>

  <div ng-controller="ctrl2">

      {{color}}

      {{root_color}}

  </div>

  </body>
```

And this is the angularjs code

```
   angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl1', ['$scope', function ctrl1($scope){

    $scope.color = "yellow";
    $scope.root_color = "red";

   }]);



   angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl2', ['$scope', function ctrl2($scope){

    $scope.color = "yellow";
    $scope.root_color = "red";

   }]);
```

Comment: Doesn't the second line redefine the app module, thus blowing away the definition of ctrl1?

Comment: While not the cause of the problem, there is no need to put a name before function.  Change 'function ctrl2' to just 'function'.  Save a few bytes of typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining controller `ctrl1` in you app then again redefining same app with `ctrl2`, which was flushing initially defined controller `ctrl1`.

And on angular side while `ng-controller` directive gets compiled it doesn't get controller with name `ctrl1`, so second time while registering second controller you should use only module name like `angular.module('app')` instead of `angular.module('app', [])`

**Code**

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl1', ['$scope',
    function ctrl1($scope) {
        $scope.color = "yellow";
        $scope.root_color = "red";
    }
]);

angular.module('app').controller('ctrl2', ['$scope',
    function ctrl2($scope) {
        $scope.color = "yellow";
        $scope.root_color = "red";
    }
]);
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're overriding the first controller with the 2nd. Use

```
var app=angular.module('app', []);
//1st controller
app.controller('ctrl1', function ctrl1($scope){

$scope.color = "yellow";
$scope.root_color = "red";

});
//2nd controller
app.controller('ctrl2', function ctrl2($scope){

$scope.color = "yellow";
$scope.root_color = "red";

});
```